# Views list with headlines from content type's select list

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a simple content type with an title field, image field and a category field( which is a select list text field). I have created a view where all the published content of this type is printed out and sorted by the category field. Everything is fine & awesome so far(and easy with the Views module).

However I would like to print out a headline above the different categories from the select list field.

I have figured out how to retrieve an array of the select list values with this:

```
$field = content_fields('field_mm_category', 'om_mm_content');
$allowed = content_allowed_values($field, TRUE);
```

But can't put it together with the other content in the views-view-nameofcontentype.tpl.php file. Is there and easy way to achieve this? Maybe using a preprocess or likewise? Or is this to lame and should i consider using a taxonomy vocabulary?

Oh and its in drupal 6:).

Edit:

The content should be printed out like this:

headline1 (which is the value from the content type's select list)

item1, item2, item3...

headline2

item4, item5, item6...

So under the first headline you will get all the content of the specific type where headline1 is chosen from the select list (and the headline1 is the value chosen).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the question here.

However, I would advise: have a look at the Views "Grouping Field" option - I believe you get this when you are using the "table-type" style of view; it appears when you are modifying your views style.  You might be able to solve your problem by simply grouping your results by category.

Comment: It does group the content together using the select list values, and also adds the select list value as a caption for that group. Whoever I think its better to get it in unformatted html.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to fiddle with the Views template (create a special template for this view), formatting it according to your own wishes.  A bit time consuming, but if it's an important part of your site, worth it.